# Blender 2.78a crashes when setting up IK system

Tags: rigging, bones, inverse-kinematics

Okay, this has wasted fifteen minutes of my entire life.

I'm using Blender 2.78a with a Windows 32-bit OS. I was just following a character creation tutorial in Youtube
and I made it till the end of setting up the bones. I added a bone constraints (IK) to my character's leg bone, and tried to set the Bone field to the IK bone I just created a while ago. Just when I select the bone, Blender crashes.

I tried doing this over and over again and luckily, Blender didn't crash one time. But when I try to grab or rotate the IK bone that controls the leg bone, Blender crashes again. Now every time I try to open the blender file in Blender's splash screen, Blender crashes.

I managed to get this screenshot luckily one time :

[image: I managed to get this screenshot luckily one time]

There's this other screenshot :

[image]

Someone PLEASE help me! I can'r proceed with 3D modelling if I don't fix this error (or maybe if I buy Win64). Thanks :)

P.S.

Mind my spelling of Character in the splash screen - I saved it in a hurry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blender shouldn't crash if you do something like this, so this is possibly a bug. Please try a recent daily build from the [buildbot](https://builder.blender.org/download/) to see if it has already been fixed. If not, please report it at [our bug tracker](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/).

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not familiar with things like these, but do I have to replace the entire Blender directory in my hard disk with the latest build zip  (extracted, of course) ?

Comment: Thanks, that did it! I downloaded the latest build and I don't notice any problems!

Comment: You don't have to overwrite anything. Just unpack somewhere and double-click blender.exe. That way you can have multiple versions on the same machine.